# Adding a comment to order in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am working on magento. I want add a functionality that when user places the order, a comment is added to the history comment of the order. I have gone through the code and come to know that the function

```
 public function addStatusHistoryComment($comment, $status = false)
```

in order.php is used to add the comment. I want to access it when user places the order. So how can i do that? Do anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*As with anything in Magento there are many ways.*

First you need to write a module. In that module you could listen for checkout success event - checkout_onepage_controller_success_action. Do that with the module etc/config.xml, e.g:

```
    <events>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <whatever>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>whatever/observer</class>
                    <method>checkout_onepage_controller_success_action</method>
                </whatever>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>
```

In your observer you load the last order, append your comment to it and then you save your order. The method you describe will work perfectly. You can also do things with the order status, doing so enables you to email the customer if need be:

```
public function checkout_onepage_controller_success_action($observer) {
    $orderIds=$observer->getData('order_ids');
    foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
        $order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
        $order->load($orderId);

        ... Do Something!

        $order->setState('processing', 'invoiced', 'Hello World!');
        $order->save();
    }
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I have the data in my session. So how can i access and append it to the comment?

Comment: Not sure I can help you any further without knowing more specifics.

Comment: As data is transferred with session, so i have data in a session variable. When user completes order, i want to retrieve the data from session and append it to order comments that are seen in admin panel. So i need to know how can i do this?

Comment: So you have access to the session on the server? Just load the order and add the comment using the method you have, surely?

Comment: Thanks man! It helped me a lot. Not the whole answer but part of it!