# Making a field hidden in address tag

Tags: php, html, magento

I have user information that is being displayed using address tag:

```
<address><?php echo $this->getShipping()->format('html') ?></address>
```

I want to make a field in the address hidden (not visible). For example, if the address tag contains

```
name:<br>address:<br>location:<br>company:<br>
```

and I want to show only name, address, and location, not the company. So how can I do that? Or there is some way of doing this while getting the data from PHP?

Comment: What framework are you using and what information is in `$this->getShipping()` ?

Comment: when not create a simple method that has ` $this->getShippingBasic()` ??? What is the limitation you have modifying  `$this->getShipping()`

Comment: I'm working on magento that is in php. $this->getShipping()->format('html') gives html with <br> tags. as i showed in the post.

Comment: @Baba: Here is a link to my other question. If you can tell me the solution to that! I don't need to do this thing!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565904/adding-a-comment-to-order-in-magento/12567373#comment16949076_12567373

Comment: Do note that `<address>` should be used for **contact information** about the **author of the nearest `<article>` ancestor**, or if there is none, the author of the document. It should not be used to mark up shipping addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using [regexes](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php), more specifically [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php) ?

```
$field = 'company';
$str = $this->getShipping()->format('html');
$str = preg_replace('/' .$field. '(.+)<br>/', '', $str);
```

Now you just need to call :

```
echo '<address>' .$str. '</address>';
```

where you want your  to be printed and it should do the trick.

If you want to remove the content of a different field, just change $field.

Answer (score -1):

Well you can just delete Company from template in Magento admin? It's under `System -> Configuration -> Customer configuration -> Address templates -> HTML`